# Why is egrep only printing the last match when I egrep the `man egrep` file?

Tags: bash, grep, manpage

Okay, so when I check the `man egrep` output, I see the word `recur` appear in many places.

One of those places is in the "`--recursive`" part of the `man egrep` file.

But, why doesn't it get found when I search the egrep output?

The following does not catch the "`--recursive`" part of the `man egrep` file:

```
man grep | grep -i "recur"
```

But why not?

Comment: try this: `man grep 2&>1 | grep -i "recur"`

Comment: are the --recursive entries boldened? Then there may be additional characters interposed. Seems to me that grep -i "re" does find the lines you look for.

Comment: It works for me. I guess my version of `man` doesn't produce all the formatting when the output is piped.

Comment: @Barmar, ...by contrast, OS X's does format even when stdout is not to a TTY. It'd probably be helpful if the OP specified their platform.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it on Linux and OS X, with different results. Probably a GNU vs. BSD issue.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe to od -c to see that bold words are emboldened two letters at a time

```
man grep | od -c

\b   g   r  \b   r   e  \b   e   p  \b
```

the lines you miss are bold.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are seeing many places where the token "recur" occurs, what you are not seeing are the control characters hidden between the characters - r, e, c, u, r. The control chars are being interpreted by your shell. In reality, in the entire man page, there are only a few places where those 5 chars appear continuously without any control (hidden) characters between them.

Try this:

```
man grep > text.out
vim text.out
```

Find the line that you are talking about. You will see the control characters being shown by vim.